# Canon 60D Menu button starts recording video?

Tags: video, canon-60d

Just bought a used (9 months old) Canon 60d. I noticed that when I'm in video mode, when I hit the Menu button, the camera starts recording. Very problematic. When I go the the quick view of the videos on the disk, then I can hit the Menu button and it goes to the Menu.

I hope this is not a serious problem. The guy that sold it to me probably won't give me my money back. Is this the way the Menu button is supposed to work when in video mode?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: can you check if Menu button was customized ? In canon cameras you can assign buttons to some other function.(Search in menu for customization of buttons)

Comment: I reset the camera so there shouldn't be any custom assignments. Thanks Stroker. If you have any other ideas.

Comment: John, the question was has anyone heard of this problem and is there a quick fix for it? I'm hoping that this malfunction isn't a part of a bigger problem. So if you've heard of this problem, maybe you know how someone worked it out. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: This is truly bizarre. I have never seen such a customization option on any camera. Since you already reset the camera, try to perform an upgrade to the latest firmware and then another reset (on some cameras it occurs automatically with the new firmware).

Comment: Thanks Ital, I will try the firmware fix. I think I am going to bring it in to Sammy's Camera today for a tech look.

Comment: Update, went to Sammy's and then spoke to Canon on phone. Camera needs to be sent to Canon to be fixed. Hopefully under warranty. No question here.

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems on my 6d where the rear buttons (ie the ones on the back panel, inc the menu button, set, arrows, spinny thing, Q, LV, etc) all started swapping roles.

I took it to canon and they swapped out the rear board under warranty and voila ! problem fixed.

I think you have a broken camera. Possibly water damaged.